# Errors Launching Pycharm in Anaconda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

[image: Error message]

I tried to launch my Pycharm in Anaconda but got the above message, I can open it directly on my desktop, not sure what is happening....
Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per error message, we can try this -

1. if JVM is installed then try to provide an environmental variable (JAVA_HOME)
2. if still doesn't work then try to download 64 bit tool.

For more info. -
[https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006949499-Error-launching-pycharm#:~:text=Error%20launching%20pycharm%20Follow&text=It%20says%3A%20%22If%20you%20already,Program%20Files%5CJetBrains%5CPyCharm2019.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006949499-Error-launching-pycharm#:%7E:text=Error%20launching%20pycharm%20Follow&text=It%20says%3A%20%22If%20you%20already,Program%20Files%5CJetBrains%5CPyCharm2019.)

**Note:** you have 64 bit operating system, please try to install 64 bit version tools only.